# Plot a function for different parameters

Tags: plotting, graphics, parametric-functions

Suppose I have a function that I want to plot for several values of a parameter all in the same window. For instance the function $f$ defined as

```
f[a_,b_,c_,d_]:= a+Sin[b]*Exp[c]-d^4
```

If I now want to plot `f[a,1,2,3]` with respect to `a` from 0 to 1  I simply write

```
Plot[f[a,1,2,3],{a,0,1}]
```

But suppose I want to instead plot `f[a,b,2,3]` same as before for a from 0 to 1 but now the parameter b takes on several values, say `b = 0,1,2,3,4` and so on. How can I do this all in the same plot (preferably with different colors on each curve corr. to the various b-values)?

Comment: You've seen `Table[]`?

Comment: I'll look it up.

Comment: @J.M.isback. OK I see what `Table[]' can do, but how can one implement it to write a smooth short code? Any tips?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use [`Table`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html) for this:

```
Plot[Evaluate@Table[f[a, b, 2, 3], {b, 0, 5, 1}], {a, 0, 1}]
```

And you can also put there multiple parameters, so [`Table`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html) will use all of them.

[image]

---

You can use [`PlotLegend`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotLegend.html) to specify the legend:

```
Plot[Evaluate@Table[f[a, b, 2, 3], {b, 0, 5, 1}], {a, 0, 1}, 
 PlotLegends -> LineLegend[Table[b, {b, 0, 5, 1}], LegendLabel -> x]]
```

[image]

Comment: ooo sexy, I'll try it out and report back here.

Comment: Is there a simple way to add names to all the lines, e.g. some type of legend that explains? I mean I know I can write PlotLegends -> {"1","2",...} and so on, but a more automatic code would be nice. Sorry to bother you so much.

Comment: @ShutupandCalculate look up [`PlotLegends`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotLegends.html).

Comment: Also, there's an undocumented option: `Evaluated` that when set to `True` operates just like using `Evaluate`.

Comment: FWIW, the docs for `Plot[]` mention the use of `Table[]` also...

Comment: Try adding `PlotTheme -> "Detailed"` as an option for `Plot` for good looking plots with automatic labels.

Comment: @rhermans I'll check it out. Thanks.

Comment: Man this answer is just all that. Thanks a lot everyone!