# Missing curves in a plot

Tags: plotting

I am trying to plot multiple curves for a particular parameter in a function `S1`, where the only variable is `t` and the rest are parameters.

```
S1[t_, alpha1_, alpha2_]:=40 + 2.82*t^(alpha1)/Gamma[alpha1 + 1]- 
   137.6*t^(alpha1)/Gamma[alpha1 + 1]-8.82*t^(2*alpha1)/Gamma[2*alpha1 + 1] - 
   52.68*t^(alpha1 + alpha2)/Gamma[alpha1 + alpha2 + 1]+
   129.61*t^(2*alpha1)/Gamma[2*alpha1 + 1]+29.85*t^(3*alpha1)/Gamma[3*alpha1 + 1];
```

For plotting, I adapted the idea from [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/96809/plot-a-function-for-different-parameters).

```
Plot[Evaluate@Table[S1[t, alpha1, 2], {alpha1, 0.1, 0.15, 0.2}], {t, 
  0, 2}, PlotLegends ->LineLegend[Table[alpha1, {alpha1, 0.1, 0.15, 0.2}], 
   LegendLabel -> alpha1]]
```

But the output shows only one curve, just for the first entry of `alpha1`.

Comment: `{alpha1, 0.1, 0.15, 0.2}` means that `alpha` runs form 0.1 to 0.15 with step 0.2, this gives you one point at `alpha=0.1`

Comment: @BlacKow oh my... I thought that this should take `alpha1` to be `0.1`, `0.15` and `0.2`, displaying three distinct curves for each `alpha1`. How can we achieve that?

Comment: Have a look [Mapping multiple parameters of a function to specific values](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5217/mapping-multiple-parameters-of-a-function-to-specific-values)

Comment: `{alpha1, {0.1, 0.15, 0.2}}` will give your points

Comment: @BlacKow Thanks dear it worked the way I wanted.

Comment: @BlacKow, please make it an answer, so we can close this QnA sucessfully.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As requested, posting my comment as an answer.
The [Table](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html) takes `{alpha1, {0.1, 0.15, 0.2}}` to iterate `alpha1` over the list

```
S1[t_, alpha_, n_] := Sin[100 alpha t];

Plot[Evaluate@Table[S1[t, alpha1, 2], {alpha1, {0.1, 0.15, 0.2}}], {t,
   0, 2}, PlotLegends -> 
  LineLegend[Table[alpha1, {alpha1, {0.1, 0.15, 0.2}}], 
   LegendLabel -> alpha1]]
```

[image]