# ParametricPlot - Several curves by different parameters

Tags: plotting, manipulate, list-manipulation, parametric-functions

I am trying to plot a set of curves f(a,b,t) along t with a,b = -10, -9, ..., 9, 10.

I can use `Manipulate` to draw 1 curve, and then change the curve shape by revising the value of a and b by dragging the button:-

```
Manipulate[ParametricPlot[{(a+b*t)/Sqrt[1-t^2], (a*t+b)/Sqrt[1-t^2]}, {t, -.9, .9}],{a, -10, 10},{b, -10, 10}]
```

But I want lots of stationary lines, not 1 dynamic line. I found a solution from [a previous post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/96809/plot-a-function-for-different-parameters?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) by using `Table`, but seems that it works for simple `Plot` but it's not applicable to `ParametricPlot`.

I tried `Table` in the following code, but there is no line being shown:-

```
ParametricPlot[Evaluate@Table[{(a+b*t)/Sqrt[1-t^2], (a*t+b)/Sqrt[1-t^2]},{a, -10, 10,1},{b, -10, 10,1}], {t, -.9, .9}]
```

How can I draw the lines?

Thanks!

Comment: You need `Flatten[]`: `ParametricPlot[Evaluate[Flatten[Table[{(a + b*t)/Sqrt[1 - t^2], (a*t + b)/Sqrt[1 - t^2]}, {a, -10, 10}, {b, -10, 10}], 1]], {t, -.9, .9}]`, which yields [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K814d.png).

Comment: Thanks! I got the same result.

Comment: (Pretty sure this is a dupe; can somebody find a question resolved by using `Flatten[]`?)